# Map the latest child of a collection with JPA and Hibernate (NotNull)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, formula

I need get last entity element from collection. I am using @JoinFormula:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula("(select * from
                     (SELECT r.id FROM review r WHERE r.book_id = id ORDER BY r.postedAt DESC)
                   where rownum = 1)")
    private Review 
    ...
}
```

And it works fantastic, but only if Book has some Review. Otherwise book isn't found. Because hibernate convert this to cross join and use condition in *WHERE* statement:

```
review_entity.id = 
 (select * from (SELECT r.id FROM review r WHERE r.book_id = id ORDER BY r.postedAt DESC) where rownum = 1)
```

Is any option here to convert JoinFormula to left join or something like this?

```
select
        book0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        book0_.title as title2_0_0_,
        book0_.version as version3_0_0_,
        (SELECT
            r.id 
        FROM
            review r 
        where
            r.book_id = book0_.id 
        ORDER BY
            r.postedAt DESC LIMIT 1) as formula1_0_,
        review1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        review1_.book_id as book_id4_1_1_,
        review1_.comment as comment2_1_1_,
        review1_.postedAt as postedAt3_1_1_ 
    from
        Book book0_ 
    left outer join
        Review review1_ 
            on (
                SELECT
                    r.id 
            FROM
                review r 
            where
                r.book_id = book0_.id 
            ORDER BY
                r.postedAt DESC LIMIT 1
        )=review1_.id 
    where
        book0_.id=?
```

Comment: vote this: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14696

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are going is a good idea. Your domain model does not match the reality that a book has many reviews. I understand that you want to only access the latest review but that is probably better done as an individual query. Otherwise, you could update your domain model to reflect the reality but still fetch the last review in a performant manner by means of Hibernate's extra-lazy property.

> "Extra-lazy" collection fetching - individual elements of the
>   collection are accessed from the database as needed. Hibernate tries
>   not to fetch the whole collection into memory unless absolutely needed
>   (suitable for very large collections)

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @OneToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @OrderBy("...")
    private List<Review> reviews; //needn't be exposed via public API

    public Review getLatestReview(){
      return reviews.get(reviews.size() - 1); //or first if ordered desc
    }
}
```

Hibernate's `@Where` clause could also be used as an alternative to limit collection to only one element.